# modifying element of fixed size tbb concurrent vector

Tags: c++, multithreading, tbb

My app has 6 threads that share a common `tbb::concurrent_vector`, t1, t2 and t3 are writers that loop through the vector, call `tbb::concurrent_vector< T, A >::operator[](size_type index)`, and modify the reference at that particular index. Threads t4, t5, t6 are readers that periodically iterate through the vector, read values at every index, and perform operations on them.

Eg t1, t2, t3:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < my_vec.size(); ++i)
{   
    my_struct& item = my_vec[i];
    if (i%2 == 0)
    {
        item.prop = some_other_var * item.prop;    
    }
    else
    {
        my_struct item2{item.prop**2, some_other_var};
        my_vec[i] = item2;
    }
    
}
```

And t4, t5, t6

```
for (const my_struct* p = my_vec.cbegin(); p != my_vec.cend(); ++p)
{
    std::cout << "thread no=" << t << ", prop=" << p->prop << std::endl;
}
```

My question is, what happens to the iterator if t1 modifies the vector while t4 is in the middle of iterating through all the elements? Does the iterator get invalidated? If not, what value is t4 expected to see, the updated value or the value before the update?

THe struct my_struct is contains only integers, and the vector is fixed size.

Answer (score 0):

According to the code, you only modify vector's elements, not vector. If so, iterators are not invalidated. There is nothing special during access via operator[], no hidden locks in it. So, t4 may see old value, new value or something in between, when only part of `my_struct` is updated.